# Creating a package from offshore team in developer edition, publish in professional

Tags: salesforce1-app, appexchange

Apologies for the long title. Here is some background.

My company has a professional edition of Salesforce. We used an offshore team to develop a Salesforce app, they used a developer edition of Salesforce for development.

They wanted to deploy the app remotely to our Salesforce edition but were not able to because Professional edition lacks a certain APEX permission.

I created a developer edition using my personal email address and they were able to deploy the app to my Salesforce edition.

In my company's account we are a member of the partner program for publishing apps.

My question is, can I create the package in my developer account and upload that from my company's partner account so it goes in the app exchange?

I have tried to create a package, but it fails due to lack of code coverage on a trigger but that is not the issue here, the issue is I am not sure if it is possible to take a package made from a developer edition and upload it to a professional edition for app exchange.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run Apex Code in Professional Edition without your code being certified by a Security Review. I'm not sure you want to go through the hassle of doing this just to be able to run your code. Also, technically, going through this process with the sole intent of getting extra functionality for free is probably an abuse of being an ISV partner. If you need Apex Code in your production org, you need to upgrade to Enterprise Edition.

Comment: I do not need extra functionality for our professional edition. The app does not need this APEX permission, the APEX permission was only needed for remote deploy. All I am asking is if I create the package in my dev account, can it be uploaded through our partner account? 2 different accounts/editions

Comment: @andrewb Packages destined for the appexchange must be uploaded from a developer edition, as "live" orgs cannot be the source of a managed package.

Comment: Okay cool but lets say my company account is "AB Ltd" and my dev account is "andrewb test" would the publisher name/author in the app store be "andrew b test"? As a company we would like the publisher name to be our company name

Comment: @andrewb Your listing will say whatever is on your Publishing profile, regardless of what your development org says.

Comment: Okay so one last thing, we are a member of the partner program (partners.salesforce.com) that membership is through my company's account, not my dev account. Do I need to get my dev account accepted in the partner program to publish apps?

Comment: @andrewb You just link your dev org to the listing, and it'll be registered appropriately. See [Connect a Packaging Org to the AppExchange](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/appexchange_publish_organizations.htm).